# Facebook Ads API rate limits

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

Facebook does not explicitly states number of API calls, or anything else regarding rate limits of their Ads API at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/

Is there another page that specifies it? Have you empirically measured what the rate limits are?

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not specify the actual rate limits anywhere sadly. Just how long you have to wait till you can request again when you've hit the limit (Graph User: 30 minutes, Ads User: 1 minute).

You can measure the rate limits, but they will differ from time to time as Facebook itself grants a score (which we can't retrieve) to the API call when you make it.